# XLSX file asking for security info in IE11 only

Tags: c#, excel, internet-explorer, xlsx

I am having an issue with XLSX files asking for login credentials for excel when I try to open the file from my site.  When I click cancel on the security question it will open the file in excel anyway with out any login credentials being added.

What I would like is that the security question to not even popup when the file is clicked. This issue only happens in IE11, all others browsers work fine, so I don't think its the code that has an issue.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Is this an issue that appears in IE11 on multiple different machines? Is this an IE11 setting or really a Web browser issue?

Comment: This issue appears in IE11 only on multiple different machines, I have now tested this on 3 different PCs using Windows 7 & 8 and the same thing happens on all of them.  If I save the file then open it, it will not ask for login credentials it will open as normal. But I just need it to open with out having to save the file.